# Chaning globally font in Angular is not working

Tags: css, angular

I downloaded Ubuntu fonts and store then under assets/fonts/Ubuntu

Here is my styles.css

```
 @font-face {  
    font-family: 'ubuntu';  
    src: url('./assets/fonts/Ubuntu/Ubuntu-Regular.ttf');
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;  
  }

  body {  
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'ubuntu';
  }  
    
  html, body {  
    margin: 0;  
    font-family: 'ubuntu';
    padding: 30px;  
  }
```

But somehow this settings are not applied. No matter what I do the font is always the same as before. I don't see any changes. Also there are no any errors in console while using developer tools.

Is there something else what i should change/add?

I'm using Angular 16 and Angular Material 16.1.5 and Firefox browser.

Comment: Do you have any 404 errors in your devtools network tab for a font file that cannot load?

Comment: @ChrisBarr everything is fine. This is what confuse me.

Comment: @AztecCodes I believe you have commented on the wrong question, haha!

Comment: @Josef when you inspect an element in the devtools, what font does it say is being applied to it?

Comment: @ChrisBarr the text which i used of testing under inspector says font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; but i don't know from where it is taking this font.

Comment: Inspect the element and view the "computed" tab of the CSS and find `font-family` - it will show you where it gets fonts from which CSS rules and what overrides what. You should either see the your font is not applied at all, or it is being overridden by some other rule

Comment: @ChrisBarr it looks like it's taking from deeppurple.amber.css because the text is under <h3> and it is applied style .mat-typography. I'm wondering why settings in style.css is not overriding that.

Comment: Not sure, but that's out of scope for this question.  Sounds like you need to either force it with `font-family: 'ubuntu' !important;`, find a way to modify the material design styles to use this font, or revise your styles in general